# Chunked QuadTree creation & handling

Tags: algorithm, quadtree

I am new to LOD-based techniques so please be lenient with your comments about my naive questions.

Preface:

My aim is a simple terrain renderer (preferred C++ and OGL) that is to load a height-map (say 990 x 990 x 8bit) organized into 33x33 vertex chunks. No on-demand paging, just the sampling vertices from the height-map data directly into the vertex-buffers of the chunks. The rendering should be done via a quadtree whereas the leafs would render a whole chunk (33x33 vertices).

After reading Thatcher Ulrich's "Adaptive Quadtree" article, as well as chunked LOD and quite many other articles and questions on stack-exchange, I still seem to be too stupid to wrap my head around on how to actually proceed. Ulrich rendered leafs as triangle-fans directly (in his demo-code) which was appropriate at that time (I guess) but my prerequisite is a batch of triangles at once, hence the chunked approach.

1) Using a quad-tree (which is easy enough to understand, at least conceptually, and will -presumably- not lead to patent-wars later as with e.g. 'geo-mipmaps'), at some point the tree will have to be created. My guess was to load (or generate) a height-map first and then PRECALCULATE a quad-tree based on this map. Would that be a viable approach? 
Various articles seem to expect the reader to know this fact a priori, so it is nowhere clearly stated. If pre-calculated, then all possible child-nodes would be pre-allocated in the RAM and walked top-down with some distance-to-node-by-width LOD criteria that would force the child-nodes to take over.

2) If pre-allocated, HOW would one render the chunks if lower LOD is required. I.e, the chunk being 32x32 quats => 33x33 vertices, an index buffer holding 33x33 indices would render the whole chunk as is. Now, a neighbor-node with one lower LOD-level is not a leave anymore, and its index buffer would not only need to span the four chunks of it children, it would also have to have an index buffer that indexes every second vertex as well to maintain only a single level of difference (or so my understanding). So I guessed (again) that EVERY node (leaf or not) would have to have (at least) one index buffer, and this index buffer would also have to be created/calculated during creation of the entire tree. (Which I would place in the engine's loading section, not anywhere close to the rendering-loop). 
What I really don't understand is, how to do the rendering with the above approach (if it were the way to go, that is)... When nodes way above (in terms of lower LOD-level, i.e. coarser resolution) must draw their content, would that mean that the vertex-buffers of ALL chunks (in the leaf nodes way down) must be bound? And how would the index buffer of this node address the vertices in all the chunks?...
Or, would one have an empty 33x33 patch standing to the ready to collect vertices from various chunks as indexed by this lower-level node? (Sounds cheesy already whilst writing this...)

I would love to see an answer to this. I would accept a NO-CAN-DO with quadtrees and alternative suggestions, but a quad-tree solution is what I hope for.

My own alternative solution (which is a whack-job on my mind though) is a kinda 'Infinite Snapshot Quadtree' that starts with a root and creates nodes on-the-fly, but does only store as many nodes as required to render the visible world. A node however must carry all information to recreate its parent as well as to be able to create a chunck-geometry. The subdivision depth with this approach is (virtually) infinite (not considering issues with precision here), but the neighbor-linking mayhem is beyond good and evil...

Best Regards.
Edward